# Где найти датасет для классификации и кластеризации людей?

Tags: нейронные-сети

Мне нужно разработать нейронную сеть для классификации и кластеризации людей. Для этого я думаю использовать теплокарты. В интернете я не смог найти готовый датасет на данную тему. Подскажите, где я могу найти такой датасет? Желательно, чтобы дата сет состоял из изображений.
Также, не обязательна классификация именно людей. Главное чтобы это была слабоформулизируемая область.

Comment: https://vincentarelbundock.github.io/Rdatasets/ https://r-dir.com/reference/datasets.html

Comment: Вам для корновируса думаю это нужно :)?  Гугл полон примеров.

Comment: А по каким признакам вы решили людей классифицировать? Про кластеризирование людей я даже боюсь спрашивать.

Answer (score 0):

Сайты для поиска дата сетов: https://www.kaggle.com/, https://datasetsearch.research.google.com/
https://www.visualdata.io/